# How do I mock static chained methods using jmockit in Java

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

How do I leverage JMockit in order to test the above code?

Comment: What would you hope to accomplish from testing the standard library?

Comment: Say, based on the host name I am setting up some attributes and taking some actions. How do I mock the above code?

Answer (score 2):

The chained method you gave is equivalent to the following:

```
InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalhost();
String hostName = localHost.getHostName();
```

Therefore, we need to break this into two mocks.

The second part is easily done by just mocking an `InetAddress` and putting it in an `Expectations` block like so:

```
@Test
public void myTest(@Mocked InetAddress mockedLocalHost) throws Exception {

    new Expectations() {{
       mockedLocalHost.getHostName();
       result = "mockedHostName";
    }};

    // More to the test
}
```

But how do we get `mockedLocalHost` to be the instance that is returned when we call `InetAddress.getLocalhost()`? With [partial mocking](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial), which can be used for any static methods. The syntax for that is to include the class containing the static method as a parameter for `new Expecations()` and then mock it as we would any other method call:

```
@Test
public void myTest(@Mocked InetAddress mockedLocalHost) throws Exception {

    new Expectations(InetAddress.class) {{
       InetAddress.getLocalHost();
       result = mockedLocalHost;

       mockedLocalHost.getHostName();
       result = "mockedHostName";
    }};

    // More to the test
}
```

This will result in mocking `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` as you planned.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to declare `@Mocked InetAddress var1`. By default, all methods of a `@Mocked` type, including static methods, return mocks. Then, the only calls to be stubbed ("recorded") in the `Expectations` are those with results important for the code being tested or those to be verified.